# Request has invalid media type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

On a Symfony 3.4 running in production I keep getting this error:

```
An Error Occurred! Uncaught PHP Exception Negotiation\Exception\InvalidMediaType: "" 
at /var/www/mywebsite/vendor/willdurand/negotiation/src/Negotiation/Accept.php line 24
```

I can hardly investigate the request as it's failing while constructing it.

The full trace is:

```
"file": "/var/www/mywebsite/vendor/willdurand/negotiation/src/Negotiation/Accept.php:24",
    "trace": [
        "/var/www/mywebsite/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/Negotiation/FormatNegotiator.php:105",
        "/var/www/mywebsite/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/EventListener/FormatListener.php:60",
        "/var/www/mywebsite/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:212",
        "/var/www/mywebsite/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44",
        "/var/www/mywebsite/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:127",
        "/var/www/mywebsite/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68",
        "/var/www/mywebsite/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:200",
        "/var/www/mywebsite/web/app.php:17"
    ]
```

The surrounding code looks like:

```php
    public function __construct($value)
    {
        parent::__construct($value);

        if ($this->type === '*') {
            $this->type = '*/*';
        }

        $parts = explode('/', $this->type);

        if (count($parts) !== 2 || !$parts[0] || !$parts[1]) {
            throw new InvalidMediaType();
        }
```

When I log the values of `$this->type` and `$value` I find them both equal to `""` (empty string).

When I try to catch this exception at the `/var/www/mywebsite/web/app.php:17` level, I keep having this error...

I really have no idea who can frequently call my website with this invalid header, and how to get rid of this polluting error log.

Any idea?

Comment: It's very likely that it is a request that has no HTTP `Accept` header, probably a bot ? Negotiation needs a media type hence the error, that can be safely ignored I think in your case. If you want to get rid of it, filter the requests beforehand if they don't have the necessary headers.

Comment: I understand, thanks. I just don't know right now at which level I can safely filter it, without coding into the symfony and willdurand's packages...

Comment: Show us the controller code so we can try to see what could be done

Comment: As you can see from the trace, it does not even reach the controller. I have many controllers in my app, and from the logs I cannot locate which route is called. It seems the exception is raised during the resolution of the route.

Comment: Well it's the Rest Bundle that uses the Negociator as I understand, so all routes managed by the rest bundles should produce the log — you can test that by issuing an invalid request yourself to see if the log shows up. There might be a way to silence these by accepting null media type in your annotations for this bundle